# How to center the contents of the first column?

Tags: tables, booktabs

How to center only the contents of the first column, without centering anything else, including the header of the first column?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ @{} l l l >{$\mathstrut\displaystyle}l<{$} @{} }
\toprule 
\emph{first} & \emph{second} & \emph{third} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\emph{fourth}} \\\midrule
foo & bar & y=f(x) & data\\
foo & bar & y=f(x) & data \\
foo & bar & Time \\
foo & bar & y=f(x) & 10.56 \\
foo & bar & Angle & 18.256 \\
foo & bar & Force & 1.6 \\
foo & bar & y=f(x) & 8.56 \\\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Use `@{} c l l`.

Comment: It works. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Since you do not want to center the header but only the cells below, you have to specify the header alignment separately using `\multicolumn`. Don't forget the `@{}` in the `\multicolumn` as well. Some notes:

- I do not think it's a good idea to have the header aligned differently than the rest of the column.
- I do not think it's a good idea to remove the `\tabcolsep` at the edges of the table using `@{}`.
- Don't write text (`data` in your example) in math mode! Use `\textit` if you want italic text (or `\itshape` if you don't need math mode), or just `\text` to escape from math mode.
- `y=f(x)`, on the other hand, should be in math mode.
- The `S` table column type of `siunitx` is a much better fit for your last column.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ @{} c l l S[table-format=2.3] @{} }\toprule 
    \multicolumn{1}{@{}l}{\emph{first}} & \emph{second} & \emph{third} & \multicolumn{1}{l@{}}{\emph{fourth}} \\\midrule
    foo long entry & bar & \(y=f(x)\) & {\itshape data long entry}\\
    foo & bar & \(y=f(x)\) & {\itshape data} \\
    foo & bar & Time \\
    foo & bar & \(y=f(x)\) & 10.56 \\
    foo & bar & Angle & 18.256 \\
    foo & bar & Force & 1.6 \\
    foo & bar & \(y=f(x)\) & 8.56 \\\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: MWE output]

For comparison, the same table with the first two points from above in mind (`@{}`s and `\multicolumn`s removed):
[image: better MWE output]

Comment: with using `makecell` package you can replace `\multicolumn{1}{@{}l}{\emph{first}}` with `\makecel[l]{\emph{first}}`. Slightly shorter ... (+1 for nice answer)

Answer (score 0):

Just change l to c

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ @{} c l l >{$\mathstrut\displaystyle$}l<{} @{} }
\toprule 
\emph{first} & \emph{second} & \emph{third} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\emph{fourth}} \\\midrule
foo & bar & y=f(x) & data\\
foo & bar & y=f(x) & data \\
foo & bar & Time \\
foo & bar & y=f(x) & 10.56 \\
foo & bar & Angle & 18.256 \\
foo & bar & Force & 1.6 \\
foo & bar & y=f(x) & 8.56 \\\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```